# Using rank() with partition by, and order by case when

Tags: sql, rank, partition, case-when

The task:

If the user has multiple projects then rank the projects in this order: 1) Photo Book 2) Card 3) any other project type

I tried to write a query that will rank for me the kinds of orders a user did. So I need to get 1 for 'photobook', 2 for 'card', and 3 for something else he ordered.

In my Excel I have only 1 order for each user, which is not at all 'photo book' or 'card' so should get for each user the number 3.

This is the query I tried:

```
select f.USER_SK,
       rank() over (partition by f.user_sk 
                          order by case when d.PROJECT_TYPE='photobook' then 1 end,                                                              
                                   case when d.PROJECT_TYPE='card' then 2 end,
                                   case when d.project_type not in ('card','photobook') then 3 end 
                         ) as [rank]
 from Project_f f inner join
      project_d d
      on f.PROJECT_SK=d.PROJECT_SK
```

The result I get, is 1 for each user although none of them bough photobook.

Comment: Sample data and an appropriate database tag would help.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't want `row_number()` at all.  I am guessing you have only one row per user.  If so:

```
   (case when d.PROJECT_TYPE = 'photobook' then 1                                                              
         when d.PROJECT_TYPE = 'card' then 2
          else 3
    end) as [rank]
```

Comment: yes you're right, but in case i have multiple orders for each user, i need to rank each one the orders for each user.
this is the task:
 If the user has multiple projects then rank the projects in this order: 1) Photo Book 2) Card 3) any other project type

Answer (score 1):

i succeeded!

-- If the user has multiple projects then rank the projects in this order: 1) Photo Book 2) Card 3) any other project type--

```
select f.user_sk, 
case 
when d.PROJECT_TYPE='photobook' then 1
when d.PROJECT_TYPE='card' then 2
else 3 end as rank
 from Project_f f inner join
      project_d d
      on f.PROJECT_SK=d.PROJECT_SK
group by f.USER_SK, d.PROJECT_TYPE
order by f.USER_SK
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over complicating things. Do you intend to have 3 separate case statements?

```
select f.user_sk, 
case 
when d.PROJECT_TYPE='photobook' then 1
when d.PROJECT_TYPE='card' then 2
else 3 end as rank
 from Project_f f inner join
      project_d d
      on f.PROJECT_SK=d.PROJECT_SK
order by rank
```

Comment: will it be helpful also if i have 3 projects for 1 user? i don't think :\

Answer (score 0):

Group by user and use conditional aggregation:

```
select f.USER_SK,
  min(
    case d.PROJECT_TYPE
      when 'photobook' then 1                                                               
      when 'card' then 2
      else 3 
    end
  ) rn
from Project_f f inner join project_d d
on f.PROJECT_SK=d.PROJECT_SK
group by f.USER_SK
```